# copiar y guardadar todos los documentos de una carpeta con java

Tags: java

hola tengo el siguiente codigo para leer todos los txt de una carpeta en especifico el problema es q los quiero guardar todos los archivos contenidos en la carpeta como una copia pero me marca error

```
       FilenameFilter filter=new FilenameFilter(){
           public boolean accept(File dir, String fileName) {
           return fileName.endsWith("docx");
           }
           };

           File f= new File(ruta_archivo);
           String [] fileList=f.list(filter);
           for (int i=0; i < fileList.length; i++){

           //System.out.println(fileList[i]);
               jTextArea1.append(fileList[i] + "\n");

           }
```

```
FileReader leer = new FileReader(ruta_archivo);

BufferedReader salida = new BufferedReader(leer, new FileOutputStream("fichero
" +".docx"));
```

Comment: y el error?? es forsozo que hagas un programa?? porque podrias usar xcopy de windows `XCOPY "C:\Folder" "D:\Backups\Folder\"` o cp en linux `cp /Folder/* /Backups/Folder/`

Comment: si para agregar todos los docx de una carpeta y q lo haga solo seleccionando la carpeta, pero el problema es q si leo una carpeta con un numero de archivos docx como hago para guardar esa misma cantidad de archivos con BufferedReader

Comment: repito, y el error??

Answer (score 0):

[FileUtils.copyDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)l)

> Copia un directorio completo a una nueva ubicación conservando las
>   fechas del archivo. Este método copia el directorio especificado y
>   todos sus directorios y archivos secundarios en el destino
>   especificado. El destino es la nueva ubicación y el nombre del
>   directorio.
>
> El directorio de destino se crea si no existe. Si el directorio de
>   destino existía, entonces este método fusiona la fuente con el
>   destino, y la fuente tiene prioridad.

```
String source = "C:/your/source";
File srcDir = new File(source);

String destination = "C:/your/destination";
File destDir = new File(destination);

try {
    FileUtils.copyDirectory(srcDir, destDir);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```